# Auto increment field not display in JTable first show

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

My table in my database has 5 field. The first field (ID) is auto increment.

This is my form to add new user:
[image](ID field not requested because it is auto increment)

Now when i add a new user, At first show, the `ID` field in not display!

[image]

And after a refresh, ID displayed: (number 24)
[image]

This is my code:

```
public class UserPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
...
    public void addAction() {
    AddUserDialog UserDialog = new AddUserDialog(this);
    Object[] myRow = new Object[]{UserDialog.getfName(), UserDialog.getlName(), UserDialog.getGender(), UserDialog.getDate()}; // how get ID here?
    if (addQuery(UserDialog.getfName(), UserDialog.getlName(), UserDialog.getGender(), UserDialog.getDate())) {
        model.addRow(myRow);
    }
}
    public boolean addQuery(String fname, String lname, String gender, String date) {
    try {
        Connection con;
        Statement statement;
        String query = "insert into UserTable(FirstName,LastName,Gender,Date) " +
                "values ( '" + fname + "' , '" + lname + "' , '" + gender + "', '" + date + "' ) ";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        statement = con.createStatement();
        if (statement.execute(query)) {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

How get ID to display at first time show?
Thanks!

Comment: it's easy to see.. you are adding my row that you created and doesn't have the `id`

Comment: @nachokk Problem is how get ID to put in myRow array?

Comment: you should use a proper `TableModel` with proper dataHolder rather than using Object[] as a dataHolder. Indeed you have to make a new a select cause you don't have the id.

Comment: @nachokk I hold data and column names an vectors in another class

Comment: just a recommendation `vector` is outdated , you should extend `AbstractTableModel` and use `List<User>` it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
    public String addQuery2(String fname, String lname, String gender, String date) throws Exception {
    String getMe = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pStatement;
        String query = "insert into UserTable(FirstName,LastName,Gender,Date) " +
                "values ( '" + fname + "' , '" + lname + "' , '" + gender + "', '" + date + "' ) ";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        pStatement = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pStatement.execute(query)
        res = pStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            getMe = String.valueOf(res.getInt(1));

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getMe;
}
```